# CTE vs Multiple joins in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I'm wondering if I am using CTEs correctly. I have two versions of a query, the first one uses a CTE and the second one uses multiple joins, both accomplish the same result.
So, my question(s) is, am I using the CTE correctly? It is more readable, but was this the intended use/ is it more efficient than the joins?

CTE QUERY:

```
WITH ASSOCIATION AS (
   SELECT PK_COLUMN AS ID,
          ENTITY_COLUMN,
          ANOTHER_ENTITY,
   FROM A
   LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID
   LEFT OUTER JOIN C ON C.ID = B.ID
   LEFT OUTER JOIN D ON D.ID = C.ID
)
SELECT COLUMNS
FROM Z 
LEFT JOIN Y ON Y.ID = Z.ID
LEFT JOIN ASSOCIATION AA ON AA.ID = Y.ID AND SOME_CONDITION
LEFT JOIN ASSOCIATION BB ON BB.ID = Y.ID AND SOME_DIFFERENT_CONDITION
```

vs

MULTIPLE JOINS QUERY:

```
SELECT COLUMNS
  FROM Z
LEFT JOIN Y ON Y.ID = Z.ID
LEFT JOIN A ON A.ID = Y.ID AND SOME_CONDITION
LEFT JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID
LEFT JOIN C ON C.ID = B.ID
LEFT JOIN D ON D.ID = C.ID
LEFT JOIN A A2 ON A2.ID ON Y.ID AND SOME_DIFFERENT_CONDITION
LEFT JOIN B B2 ON A2.ID = B2.ID
LEFT JOIN C C2 ON C2.ID = B2.ID
LEFT JOIN D D2 ON D2.ID = C2.ID
```

Comment: Yes you are using them correctly, non-recursive CTEs are syntactic sugar and offer no performance benefits, just aesthetic ones. If you compare the execution plans of your two queries I would imagine they would be the same plan if they both achieve the same result

Comment: The second query flattens the join. Depending on how smart the Query Rewriter is it may or may not flatten them as you want. This functionality changes per database version. To be sure, get the execution plans and compare them.

Comment: The query expansion process is complex genius and I would imagine both queries would end up with the same plan and some of those outer joins at least will be discarded. The only way to be sure is compare the execution plans.

Comment: You can check out the query plans and see how it looks. I have a feeling it might be similar for both, but since this is SQL Server, nothing beats testing it on your concrete data and SQL Server version

Comment: @siggemannen I have the comparison up using my data and they are not identical. I'm not an expert on reading these but the only noticeable difference I see is on the joins query, one of the joins to table A costs 43% and has an actual row read count of 23k. No rows read count comes close to that in the CTE query. The joins query gets a 'Missing index' msg and the tree/plan structure for the CTE is slightly smaller if that means anything, here is a pic: https://i.imgur.com/RPEpNQm.png

Comment: It is unclear if your two queries are equivalent.  Where does PK_COLUMN come from?  Regardless:  Unless PK_COLUMN is contains the same values as A.ID, they don't match.

Comment: In fact, all of your ID fields appear to be the same.  A.ID = B.ID = C.ID = D.ID.  So why aren't all of the references in your joins  = Y.ID?  And what is included in "COLUMNS" may make a difference.  It's likely possible to improve your second query so that the CTE isn't needed/desired, but it's difficult to tell given the other problems with the query.  Maybe post actual code you're using?